# Disable hover which show information about the symbol/object in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I just disable the hover feature which brings up the information about symbol/object in VS Code.

[image]

Link to that feature - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-hovers

I can use the following setting to disable the hover but this also removes quick fix hovers too which I use always

[image]

> "editor.hover.enabled": true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix this problem by setting `false` to these features.

```
//Remove parameter hint box
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,

//Disable hover
"editor.hover.enabled": false,

//Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions.enabled": false,
```

That is for newer versions of Visual Studio. If anyone uses older versions, you can try this

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
"editor.hover": false,
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,
```

Comment: This removes the hover completely, the OP (and I) wanted to keep the quickfix hover, and just remove the documentation part.

Answer (score 0):

Each extension adds its own part to the hover. You can disable just the documentation (and keep the quickfix part) by configuring each extension:

[image]